# How this.each(function() in jquery works?

Tags: jquery, web-applications

I'm trying to build a web app using Jquery. I've created a function and declared it globally, after calling it I'm using this.each(function () and trying to execute the function requirements in which I'm not getting the desired result. I've checked the syntax too and have received no errors.
Following is the code where I'm calling the function:

```
$('[data-nitspagelabel]').click(function () { //click function on editable div to get editable buttons
            var nitsedit = $(this);
            var labeltype = $(this).data("nitslabeltype");
            if (labeltype == "text") {
                if (modal == false) {
                    modal = true;
                    $('[data-nitstextbutton]').css({ //popup text editing buttons 
                        'top': mouseY
                        , 'left': mouseX
                    }).fadeIn(400).click(function (e) {
                        var popupbox = $(this).attr('href');
                        openPopup(popupbox); // opens the editing tools popup
                        $(nitsedit).nitspopupeditor; // formatting buttons in action
                        $(nitsedit).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

And following is the function where I've declared it globally

```
 $.fn.nitspopupeditor = function () { //Function to format editable items.
        this.each(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {}, 100);
            var $this = $(this);
            var selected_text = null;
            var uniquid = "nits" + new Date().getTime();

            $this.attr('data-nitsselect', uniquid); //set element unique id
```

I don't know where I'm doing mistake but things inside the function is not working properly.

Comment: `this` inside your function would be `window`, what are you trying to loop?

Comment: you mean, I need to replace `this` with `window` in 2nd line in `$.fn.nitspopeditor`.

Comment: `this` inside each is not eq `window`. From my best knowledge `this` inside each is current loop value.

Comment: No, what I mean is `this` will point to `window` instance.

Comment: @VasylMoskalov  I am talking about the `this` in `this.each` code

Comment: can you review this code in js fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nitishkmr09/c56hzmmt/1/)

Comment: If you can tell what is the requirement I may be able to help. Also what was your intention in using `this.each`. what item do you want to loop?

Comment: I'm trying to build a text editor for content editable div, once we hover the editable item we display a edit button which shows the editing button on popup and this editable text area is formatted accordingly, for time being I've only mentioned the bold and italics for testing purpose.

Comment: So how is this stuff related to the loop you are talking about in the question.

Comment: I want to have a selection portion where I can format the things accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

.each is iterator, that takes each element of array on each iteration.
Access to current element you may get using `$this`, so you should send an array to your .each method

here is examples
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/